# cakephp facebook api, FB->api('/me') returns empty value

Tags: facebook, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I use [Webtechnick Facebook plugin](http://www.webtechnick.com/wtn/blogs/view/229/CakePHP_Facebook_Plugin_Auth_Facebook_and_more) for cakephp 1.3 website. I implemented it about a year ago. And it worked fine until now. But today I found out that when I try to login(as a new user) it does not save facebook user data, because `$this->Connect->user()` (which result is taken from `$this->FB->api('/me')`, `/plugins/facebook/controller/components/connect.php, line 194`) returns nothing. I tried also, [this facebook plugin](https://github.com/stefan-zh/Facebook-Connect-Plugin-CakePHP) on another cakephp 2.0 website, but the same thing was there.

I think, that there was some change in facebook api, because I did not absolutely make any change on the website, which could bring to that result.

this is `user` function in `connect.php` component

```
function user($field = null){       
    if(isset($this->uid)){
        $this->uid = $this->uid;
        if($this->Controller->Session->read('FB.Me') == null){
            $this->Controller->Session->write('FB.Me', $this->FB->api('/me'));
        }
        $this->me = $this->Controller->Session->read('FB.Me');

    } 
    else {
        $this->Controller->Session->delete('FB');
    }

    if(!$this->me){
        return null;
    }

    if($field){
        $retval = Set::extract("/$field", $this->me);
        return empty($retval) ? null : $retval[0];
    }

    return $this->me;
}
```

and my `beforeFacebookSave()` function in `app_controller`

```
public function beforeFacebookSave() {
    $fbUser = $this->Connect->user ();


           //debug($fbUser);  // outputs nothing


        $this->Connect->authUser ['User'] ['email'] = $fbUser ['email'];        
        $this->Connect->authUser ['User'] ['first_name'] = $fbUser ['first_name'];
        $this->Connect->authUser ['User'] ['last_name'] = $fbUser ['last_name'];

            return true;

}
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a certificate change on Facebook that wasn't reflected in the SDK (because it used the old certificate). Since the plugin is based on PHP SDK, you should just fetch the latest version of the repo https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin. The author has pushed the commit to include the new PHP SDK with the new certificate.

https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin/tree/master/Vendor

Your error log should have a Facebook Exception due to SSL problems which chokes the API calls causing `/me` to return empty.

Comment: Thank you very much phwd, that's it ! I changed Vendor's folder and both versions worked ok. Thank you !!

Comment: Hey John, I'm having a similar issue on one of my CakePHP 1.3 sites. Can you describe in more detail how you managed to get it working? I have tried to update the cert and even rest of the PHP SDK files from webtechnick's master branch but didn't have much luck. Any specific steps/instructions you can provide will be very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hi, i have same as issue as jesal, anybody can help me . what we have to do for that?

Answer (score 0):

try this, it work for me

```
$infos = $facebook->api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,picture,email');
```